# Android studio build error: InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private transient

Tags: android, android-studio, error-handling, build, java-17

Facing this issue in the latest Android Studio (Android Studio Flamingo) with Java 17.
Getting the below error after some files adding/modifying code in files(XML or .KT) when I try to create the build.

Error details are in the below image.

[image]

**Error:**

> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to
> make field private transient java.lang.Object
> java.lang.Throwable.backtrace accessible: module java.base does not
> "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @4e7dc304

`

Even after running --scan also we are not knowing where is the problem.
It's not pointing to where is the issue in the code.
Someone, please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Your error is coming from the `ktlintFormat` task. That lines up with [this issue](https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint/issues/1391) for the ktlint library, which outlines some workarounds.

Comment: @CommonsWare there is no solution in this above link.

Comment: See [this comment](https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint/issues/1391#issuecomment-1090990781), [this comment](https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint/issues/1391#issuecomment-1181253493), [this comment](https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint/issues/1391#issuecomment-1251287020), and [this comment](https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint/issues/1391#issuecomment-1331954612) for some suggestions from other users.